# error when install Ubuntu 14.04 with easyBCD

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I try to install Ubuntu14.04 with easyBCD, but error occurred. it says

```
ERROR22:not found such partition.
```

I set the setting of bcd like this :

```
title Install Ubuntu
root (hd0,0)
kernel (hd0,0)/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso ro quiet splash locale=zh_CN.UTF-8
initrd (hd0,0)/initrd.lz
```

could anyone tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [PowerIso](http://www.poweriso.com/download.htm) to make a bootable USB and use grub as bootmenu? Run it as administrator.

[image]

Comment: If that's the case, then mark the answer as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively try chain loading either Ubuntu partition record or GRUB boot.img file
as proposed in [Dual boot Windows and Linux Or Unix](http://www.boyans.net/DualBootWindows7andLinuxOrUnix.html).

The method uses a Windows 7/8 boot sector loader to chain load GRUB.